# Rails background job with status monitoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background

I have done quite a bit of reading on background libraries/engines for ruby/rails (including Resque, Starling and workling, BackgroundJob and delayed_job), however, I unsure of whether you can establish the progress of a current job using any of the above, or other, engine?

I am stripping some audio out of a file with ffmpeg and would like to be able to provide some progress on how the job is coming along.  I thought I could poll status of jobs using one of the above but I am unsure if that is possible.

Any suggestions on whether I can poll for progress using some job engine on ruby/rails?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Does the [resque-progress gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/resque-progress) help you?

You could use it to pass the progress amount back that way.

Comment: I've not. But I know people who have.